# cannot translate category name for different store view

Tags: category, magento-1, store-view, localisation

I'm trying to translate category name for different store view, but unchecking the "Use Default Value" checkbox does nothing. Category name field stays inactive. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Firebug or similar tool and observe for errors. What you have is wrong behavior and since correct behavior is provided via JavaScript, look for problems there.

Comment: You are right. This behavior only happens with Chrome. It works with firefox. Thank you!